# How do I filter a ManyToMany field?

Tags: django

I have a model Called Parent. In the model I have a ManyToManyfield called partner_types. which is based on the model Partner_type. What I want to do is filter the model to check if someone is a parent or not.

I tried filter sets but the problem is my partner_type is defined in the admin so I am not able to filter it.

```
class PartnerType(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(blank=False,
                        help_text="Name of the role or function", max_length=64,
                        verbose_name="Partner Type", )

class Partner(TimeStampedModel, StatusModel):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, verbose_name='Account Name', )
    partner_types = models.ManyToManyField(PartnerType)
```

so my current partner types created in the admin are : 
Broker,
Service,
Distributor,
Customer,
Parent

Here is what I have tried.

```
a = Partner.objects.filter(partner_types= Partner)
```

but it does not work.

I have also tried.

```
a = Partner.objects.filter(partner_types = 4) for the numerical value of the many to many field object.
```

Comment: What do your models look like?

Comment: sorry posted my models. I first post then add code so ican see what it looks like when i post it..

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, depending on how exactly your view's information that "parent" is the `PartnerType` you're interested in is represented.

One way is to filter on the related `CharField`:

```
a = Partner.objects.filter(parter_types__name="parent")
```

If you have actually loaded the `PartnerType` instance, you can provide that directly:

```
parent = ParterTypes.objects.get(name="parent") # or whatever
...
a = Partner.objects.filter(parter_types=parent)
```

Your id-based query `Partner.objects.filter(partner_types=4)` is also valid, so if that didn't get the results you expect you might need do some data checking. But it's generally a bad idea to rely on hardcoded PKs as opposed to content-based filters.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
a=Partner.objects.filter(partnertype__name="Parent")
```